# Autcomplete Jquery UI doesnt work at first enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I've got an issue that drive me crazy, I'm not a pro in javascript and I'm sure, the answer is easy.

I use the jquery ui aucomplete and I use data got from Ajax.
I have the result I want only when I delete, the word and retype it.

There is some screens and my code for help :)

[image: Image autocomplétion]

```
var noms = new Array();

function pushNoms(nom) {
    noms.push(nom);
    console.log(noms);
}

function ajaxRequest() {
    var $search = $('#searchListDossier');
    var request = '?objet=dossier&action=autoComplete&search=' + $search.val();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', request);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
        //crea tableau
        for (var i = 0; i < this.response.length; i++) {
            pushNoms(this.response[i].nom);
        }
    });
    xhr.send();
}
$('#searchListDossier').donetyping(function() {
    ajaxRequest();
    console.log(noms);
    $('#searchListDossier').autocomplete({
        source: noms
    });
});
```

Comment: Very confused at why you're opting to use `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `$.ajax` when you're already using jQuery... but anyway... have you looked at the example on the site for remote data? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This example code does not appear to be complete. Where is the `autocomplete` code?

Comment: autocomplete is a jquery ui function :
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I used the jquery function : getJson who did the job instead of my own javascript ajax function.
Thanks for helping :)